# Why are these constraints not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, constraints, autolayout

I´ve got a scrollview that I want to add in the viewDidLoad method to my superview. I do this with following code:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.scroll];
NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scroll
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.view
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                            multiplier:1
                              constant:0]];
[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scroll
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                   multiplier:1
                                                     constant:0]];
[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scroll
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                   multiplier:1
                                                     constant:0]];
[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scroll
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                   multiplier:0.5
                                                     constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

The scrollview is intended to be placed at the bottom of the view and it's height should be half the height of the superview.

I get following error:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
```

(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Can please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you create the scroll view in code?

Comment: nope, it's placed in the nib file but outside the view... so that I can see all elements placed in the scrollview... I have an outlet called scroll (self.scroll in the code fragment)

Comment: You could try adding [self.scroll setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; to see if that helps, but usually you only need to do that if the view was created in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rdelmar solved this question:

You could try adding [self.scroll setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]